# How does Connexion set the response content type?

Tags: swagger, openapi, connexion

Below is an API *.yml section. I want to set the response header for the data to be `Content-type: text/plain`, but it always returns `application/json` now.

```
  /order:
    post:
      tags:
        - order
      summary: order
      operationId: PostOrder
      parameters:
      requestBody:
        description: Order result
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                openReq:
                  type: string
                  example: 'test'

      responses:
        200:
          description: Customer order receive successed
          headers: {}
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: string
            text/plain:
              schema:
                type: string
```

The response is returned by this python code:

```
def post_order(platform, open_req=None):  # noqa: E501
    """order

    """
    return 'do some magic!'
```

The response header is always `content-type: application/json`

```
      responses:
        200:
          description: Customer order receive successed
          headers: {}
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: string
            text/plain:
              schema:
                type: string
```

This response header for this snippet is always `content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`

```
      responses:
        200:
          description: Customer order receive successed
          headers: {}
          content:
#            application/json:
#              schema:
#                type: string
            text/plain:
              schema:
                type: string
```

Can I set the response header content type in function `post_order`?

Comment: Your definition is valid. Can you explain in more detail what the issue is and when it happens? Does your API server always return JSON even if clients request `text/plain`? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

If you want your function to decide dynamically which content-type to return, you have to set the header explicitly as explained in the [documentation](https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/response.html#returning-headers).

One of the two methods is to return a tuple of the content, the return code and a dictionary of headers like this:

```py
def post_order(platform, open_req=None): 
    """order

    """
    return 'do some magic!', 200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'}
```

The second method is to create a response object explicitly and return that:

```py
from connexion.lifecycle import ConnexionResponse

def post_order(platform, open_req=None): 
    """order

    """
    return ConnexionResponse(
        status_code=200,
        content_type='text/plain',
        body='do some magic!'
    )
```

This gives you more control for other adjustments. But it is not necessary if the simple tuple solution works in your case.

Comment: it's worth mentioning for my app the first method did not work at all, headers were overwritten somewhere with `application/json`, the second at least set the `content-type` headers correctly, but failed to do the necessary magic to display csv without "\r\n" directly in the output. The only thing that DID work was doing `flask.Response(result, mimetype="text/csv")`

Comment: But this is the documented way and I've been using it for some time. Maybe you have some other middleware which interacts with your endpoints?

Comment: It's possible, but all I'm using extra is Swagger and Flask, maybe Swagger is the culprit, but even that is kind of silly because Connexion fully supports that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending something with a specific mimetype the accepted answer will not work, I was trying to send `text/csv` and the only thing that worked (to not get `/r/n` in the response as chars and not producing newlines, using `Connexion/flask/swagger-ui`) is this

```
from connexion.lifecycle import ConnexionResponse

def post_order(platform, open_req=None): 
    """order"""
    return ConnexionResponse(
        status_code=200,
        content_type='text/csv',
        mimetype='text/csv',  # <----
        body='do some magic!'
    )
```

*Explanation:*

The first method from the previous answer did simply not work for me

```
def post_order(platform, open_req=None): 
   """order"""
    return 'do some magic!', 200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'}
```

some other step in my setup changed the content-type back to `application/json` when I was trying to send `text/csv`.

However, the second method

```
from connexion.lifecycle import ConnexionResponse

def post_order(platform, open_req=None): 
    """order"""
    return ConnexionResponse(
        status_code=200,
        content_type='text/plain',
        body='do some magic!'
    )
```

did change the `content-type` correctly when set to `text/csv`, BUT did not set the mimetype correctly and it took me a while to figure out why I was getting the string with `/r/n` in it without producing newlines. That was probably because Connexion was STILL trying to render the response as JSON instead of the intended `text/csv`.

The solution I posted was the only thing that worked, except using a flask response directly, which I will include here as well, that tipped me to the solution

```
from flask import Response

def post_order(platform, open_req=None): 
   """order"""
    return Response('do some magic!', mimetype='text/csv')
```

ConnexionResponse "docs" (it's the source code): https://github.com/spec-first/connexion/blob/9be473d5eabebde3df8d50e69f46513a66bba497/connexion/lifecycle.py

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you are confusing the API Swagger Docs with the actual implementation, your documentation is correct, it means the response `200 OK`, can return as `application/json` or `text/plain`. Which one is returned depends solely on your implementation of the endpoint. If your endpoint only returns `application/json`, then you will never receive `text/plain`, that is not Swagger/OpenApi's Job.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, do you know how connexion set response header type